# offsetHeight, clientHeight and scrollHeight does not give the correct height

Tags: javascript, css, height

I've read about **offsetHeight**, **clientHeight** and **scrollHeight**. Still I can't figure out how to set the correct height to a div that can include:

- box-sizing
- padding
- margin
- border
- something else that may push the div

In my example below I've made 4 sections. The first section is untouched so the height on that one is auto and correct. When I try to set the height in the other sections with offsetHeight, clientHeight and scrollHeight the results are no longer correct.

**How can I calculate it in a way that it's always working?** I've seen many answers here on Stackoverflow but no reliable solution.

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
  let items1 = document.querySelectorAll('.section1 div');
  let items2 = document.querySelectorAll('.section2 div');
  let items3 = document.querySelectorAll('.section3 div');
  
  items1.forEach((item) => {    
    item.style.height = item.offsetHeight + 'px';
  });
  
  items2.forEach((item) => {    
    item.style.height = item.clientHeight + 'px';
  });
  
  items3.forEach((item) => {    
    item.style.height = item.scrollHeight + 'px';
  });
});
```

```css
.div1 {
  border: 5px solid #fff;
  padding: .5rem;
  margin: .5rem;
  box-sizing: border-box;
 }
 
 .div2 {
  border: 5px solid #fff;
  padding: .5rem;
  margin: .5rem;
 }
 
 .div3 {
  padding: .5rem;
  margin: .5rem;
  box-sizing: border-box;
 }
 
 .div4 {
  padding: .5rem;
  margin: .5rem;  
 }
 
 .div5 {
 }
 
 div[class^=div] {
   background: #eee;
   outline: 1px solid red;
 }
 
 body {
   display: flex;
 }
 
 section {
   background: #f5f5f5;
   margin: .5rem;
   width: 100px;
 }
```

```html
<section class="correct">
  <div class="div1">Some<br>text</div>
  <div class="div2">Some<br>text</div>
  <div class="div3">Some<br>text</div>
  <div class="div4">Some<br>text</div>
  <div class="div5">Some<br>text</div>
</section>

<section class="section1">
  <div class="div1">Some<br>text</div>
  <div class="div2">Too<br>High</div>
  <div class="div3">Some<br>text</div>
  <div class="div4">Too<br>high</div>
  <div class="div5">Some<br>text</div>
</section>

<section class="section2">
  <div class="div1">Too<br>low</div>
  <div class="div2">Too<br>high</div>
  <div class="div3">Some<br>text</div>
  <div class="div4">Too<br>high</div>
  <div class="div5">Some<br>text</div>
</section>

<section class="section3">
  <div class="div1">Too<br>low</div>
  <div class="div2">Too<br>high</div>
  <div class="div3">Some<br>text</div>
  <div class="div4">Too<br>high</div>
  <div class="div5">Some<br>text</div>
</section>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "correct height"? You mean the natural height the div gets when its children are created in the DOM?

Comment: The inner height if you will. None of the last three sections matches the first one. I've added my own answer to this question which I think is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many tests I've figured it out. The solution is to use `getComputedStyle(item).getPropertyValue('height')`.

In the below example the first one is untouched and the second one set the height with the above.

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
  let items4 = document.querySelectorAll('.section4 div');
  
  items4.forEach((item) => {    
    item.style.height = getComputedStyle(item).getPropertyValue('height');
  });
});
```

```css
.div1 {
  border: 5px solid #fff;
  padding: .5rem;
  margin: .5rem;
  box-sizing: border-box;
 }
 
 .div2 {
  border: 5px solid #fff;
  padding: .5rem;
  margin: .5rem;
 }
 
 .div3 {
  padding: .5rem;
  margin: .5rem;
  box-sizing: border-box;
 }
 
 .div4 {
  padding: .5rem;
  margin: .5rem;  
 }
 
 .div5 {
 }
 
 div[class^=div] {
   background: #eee;
   outline: 1px solid red;
 }
 
 body {
   display: flex;
 }
 
 section {
   background: #f5f5f5;
   margin: .5rem;
   width: 100px;
 }
```

```html
<section class="correct">
  <div class="div1">Some<br>text</div>
  <div class="div2">Some<br>text</div>
  <div class="div3">Some<br>text</div>
  <div class="div4">Some<br>text</div>
  <div class="div5">Some<br>text</div>
</section>

<section class="section4">
  <div class="div1">Some<br>text</div>
  <div class="div2">Not too<br>High =)</div>
  <div class="div3">Some<br>text</div>
  <div class="div4">Not too<br>high =)</div>
  <div class="div5">Some<br>text</div>
</section>
```

Comment: In this case, it's like you are doing nothing ... you are reading the property and then putting that value in the same property. I thought you want to find to have that height differently

Comment: @TemaniAfif In this exact example, yes. Another case would be to take a height from one element and place it to another element. I just released my first version of my Vanilla Match Height script https://github.com/jenstornell/vanilla-match-height.js

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you are randomly applying the `box-sizing`. You should apply them to all the elements inside the same section or not at all but not to only few of them.

The correct result is the first one with `box-sizing:border-box` applied.

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
  let items1 = document.querySelectorAll('.section1 div');
  let items2 = document.querySelectorAll('.section2 div');
  let items3 = document.querySelectorAll('.section3 div');

  items1.forEach((item) => {
    item.style.height = item.offsetHeight + 'px';
  });

  items2.forEach((item) => {
    item.style.height = item.clientHeight + 'px';
  });

  items3.forEach((item) => {
    item.style.height = item.scrollHeight + 'px';
  });
});
```

```css
.div1 {
  border: 5px solid #fff;
  padding: .5rem;
  margin: .5rem;
}

.div2 {
  border: 5px solid #fff;
  padding: .5rem;
  margin: .5rem;
}

.div3 {
  padding: .5rem;
  margin: .5rem;
}

.div4 {
  padding: .5rem;
  margin: .5rem;
}

div[class^=div] {
  background: #eee;
  outline: 1px solid red;
}

body {
  display: flex;
}

section {
  background: #f5f5f5;
  margin: .5rem;
  width: 100px;
}

.section1 >*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<section class="correct">
  <div class="div1">Some<br>text</div>
  <div class="div2">Some<br>text</div>
  <div class="div3">Some<br>text</div>
  <div class="div4">Some<br>text</div>
  <div class="div5">Some<br>text</div>
</section>

<section class="section1">
  <div class="div1">Some<br>text</div>
  <div class="div2">Too<br>High</div>
  <div class="div3">Some<br>text</div>
  <div class="div4">Too<br>high</div>
  <div class="div5">Some<br>text</div>
</section>

<section class="section2">
  <div class="div1">Too<br>low</div>
  <div class="div2">Too<br>high</div>
  <div class="div3">Some<br>text</div>
  <div class="div4">Too<br>high</div>
  <div class="div5">Some<br>text</div>
</section>

<section class="section3">
  <div class="div1">Too<br>low</div>
  <div class="div2">Too<br>high</div>
  <div class="div3">Some<br>text</div>
  <div class="div4">Too<br>high</div>
  <div class="div5">Some<br>text</div>
</section>
```

Adding `box-sizing` to the other will make them smaller because both don't include the border in the calculation and the value given will later include the border.

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
  let items1 = document.querySelectorAll('.section1 div');
  let items2 = document.querySelectorAll('.section2 div');
  let items3 = document.querySelectorAll('.section3 div');

  items1.forEach((item) => {
    item.style.height = item.offsetHeight + 'px';
  });

  items2.forEach((item) => {
    item.style.height = item.clientHeight + 'px';
  });

  items3.forEach((item) => {
    item.style.height = item.scrollHeight + 'px';
  });
});
```

```css
.div1 {
  border: 5px solid #fff;
  padding: .5rem;
  margin: .5rem;
}

.div2 {
  border: 5px solid #fff;
  padding: .5rem;
  margin: .5rem;
}

.div3 {
  padding: .5rem;
  margin: .5rem;
}

.div4 {
  padding: .5rem;
  margin: .5rem;
}

div[class^=div] {
  background: #eee;
  outline: 1px solid red;
}

body {
  display: flex;
}

section {
  background: #f5f5f5;
  margin: .5rem;
  width: 100px;
}

.section1 >*,
.section2 >*,
.section3 >*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<section class="correct">
  <div class="div1">Some<br>text</div>
  <div class="div2">Some<br>text</div>
  <div class="div3">Some<br>text</div>
  <div class="div4">Some<br>text</div>
  <div class="div5">Some<br>text</div>
</section>

<section class="section1">
  <div class="div1">Some<br>text</div>
  <div class="div2">Too<br>High</div>
  <div class="div3">Some<br>text</div>
  <div class="div4">Too<br>high</div>
  <div class="div5">Some<br>text</div>
</section>

<section class="section2">
  <div class="div1">Too<br>low</div>
  <div class="div2">Too<br>high</div>
  <div class="div3">Some<br>text</div>
  <div class="div4">Too<br>high</div>
  <div class="div5">Some<br>text</div>
</section>

<section class="section3">
  <div class="div1">Too<br>low</div>
  <div class="div2">Too<br>high</div>
  <div class="div3">Some<br>text</div>
  <div class="div4">Too<br>high</div>
  <div class="div5">Some<br>text</div>
</section>
```

Note that `scrollHeight` and `clientHeight` are the same here since there is no overflow.

---

> Typically, `offsetHeight` is a measurement in pixels of the element's CSS height, including any borders, padding, and horizontal scrollbars (if rendered). <sup>[ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetHeight)</sup>
>
> The `scrollHeight` value is equal to the minimum height the element would require in order to fit all the content in the viewport without using a vertical scrollbar. The height is measured in the same way as `clientHeight`: it includes the element's padding, but not its border, margin or horizontal scrollbar (if present). It can also include the height of pseudo-elements such as ::before or ::after. If the element's content can fit without a need for vertical scrollbar, its `scrollHeight` is equal to `clientHeight` <sup>[ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollHeight)</sup>

**UPDATE**

If you want a generic way then you need to test the `box-sizing`. If `border-box` you consider `offsetHeight`, if not you consider `clientHeight` minus padding:

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
  let items = document.querySelectorAll('section:not(.correct) div');
  
  items.forEach((item) => {
    var e = window.getComputedStyle(item);
    var b = e.boxSizing;
    if(b =="border-box")
      item.style.height = item.offsetHeight + 'px';
    else 
      var p = parseFloat(e.paddingTop) + parseFloat(e.paddingBottom);
      item.style.height = (item.clientHeight - p) + 'px';
  });

});
```

```css
.div1 {
  border: 5px solid #fff;
  padding: .5rem;
  margin: .5rem;
  box-sizing: border-box;
 }
 
 .div2 {
  border: 5px solid #fff;
  padding: .5rem;
  margin: .5rem;
 }
 
 .div3 {
  padding: .5rem;
  margin: .5rem;
  box-sizing: border-box;
 }
 
 .div4 {
  padding: .5rem;
  margin: .5rem;  
 }
 
 .div5 {
 }
 
 div[class^=div] {
   background: #eee;
   outline: 1px solid red;
 }
 
 body {
   display: flex;
 }
 
 section {
   background: #f5f5f5;
   margin: .5rem;
   width: 100px;
 }
```

```html
<section class="correct">
  <div class="div1">Some<br>text</div>
  <div class="div2">Some<br>text</div>
  <div class="div3">Some<br>text</div>
  <div class="div4">Some<br>text</div>
  <div class="div5">Some<br>text</div>
</section>

<section class="section1">
  <div class="div1">Some<br>text</div>
  <div class="div2">Too<br>High</div>
  <div class="div3">Some<br>text</div>
  <div class="div4">Too<br>high</div>
  <div class="div5">Some<br>text</div>
</section>

<section class="section2">
  <div class="div1">Too<br>low</div>
  <div class="div2">Too<br>high</div>
  <div class="div3">Some<br>text</div>
  <div class="div4">Too<br>high</div>
  <div class="div5">Some<br>text</div>
</section>

<section class="section3">
  <div class="div1">Too<br>low</div>
  <div class="div2">Too<br>high</div>
  <div class="div3">Some<br>text</div>
  <div class="div4">Too<br>high</div>
  <div class="div5">Some<br>text</div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to change anything in my CSS. I want to rewrite my javascript so that can get/set the correct height on any element no matter the box-sizing.

Comment: Yes, that should work. You calculate the element depending on if it has a box-sizing or not. I have found a solution where I don't need to do the calculation myself. It's to use `getComputedStyle(element).getPropertyValue('height')`. You can see my answer if you like.